# Unable to get the response from the API

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

**Scenario**
I'm sending a request payload to the API that further calls the SMS service provider in the in-sequence flow, I need to share back the response from the SMS service provider as it is. The API works fine and I do receive SMS on phone but I'm unable to share back the response from the service provider in the out sequence flow.

The response body from my SMS service provider is actually **text** as shown:
[image]

The  Response header of SMS Service Provider looks like this:
[image]

**API**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/mobilink" name="MobilinkSmsApi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/send">
        <inSequence>
            <property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
            <property description="username" expression="json-eval($.username)" name="uri.var.username" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="password" expression="json-eval($.password)" name="uri.var.password" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="to" expression="json-eval($.to)" name="uri.var.to" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="from" expression="json-eval($.from)" name="uri.var.from" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="message" expression="json-eval($.message)" name="uri.var.message" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri-template="https://coXXXXX.XXXX.com/sendsms_url.html?Username={uri.var.username}&amp;Password={uri.var.password}&amp;From={uri.var.from}&amp;To={uri.var.to}&amp;Message={uri.var.message}">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log category="TRACE" level="full"/>
            <property description="Content-Type" name="Content-Type" scope="default" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <log category="ERROR" level="full"/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Question**
My Question is how to share back the response from the service provider in the out sequence? I tried to use property with value **text/html** and even used content-type as **text/html** but It didn't worked.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Btw I couldn't find a `<respond/>` mediator after the call mediator in your insequence. To send the response back to the client you need to have Respond Mediator.

Comment: the <respond/> mediator is in the out-sequence

Comment: @sanoJ if i want to convert the text respond to json, what exactly do i need to do?

Comment: Since you are getting a text value, you may use a Payloadfactory to create a JSON object and pass that to the client

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this. either one of below mentioned way you can follow

1. place  `<respond/>` after `<call>` mediator
2. Use `<Send>` mediator instead of `<call>`, so that flow will come from insequence  to outsequence where you already placed `<respond/>` to send back message to client

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved when I placed the  mediator in the inSequence flow.
previously I was placing the mediator in the outSequence